# How can multiple Buttons in fragment load different data

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

[image]

This is the UI, I want to the top button onclick different data but not move another fragment.
My architecture use the courutine Room,

Comment: you have to explain problem more

Comment: You can keep the layout same and implement Tablayout using Viewpager. That will load different data for every tab. But if you don't want that then put a layout container in your Main activity layout and put a fragment there at run time, then load different fragments with different data on click of those top buttons.

Comment: @User9211 How about i use detach an attach ? can i bring another data?

Comment: you can try, hope that works as you expect